# Einstein General relativity and bending of space

Tags: general-relativity, space-time

As Einstein's General relativity suggests that the space 
time curves in the presence of matter, which is experimentally
proven too, this phenomenon also explains orbits. My question
is if the presence of mass curves space-time, in which direction 
does it bend, if we assume that it bends in one of all possible
directions then what makes the body to choose that particular 
direction. Does all the bodies bend the space-time in the same
direction ?

Comment: (v1) It is very unclear as to what this question is asking, but I strongly suspect that one of the OP's confusions is regarding the difference between intrinsic and extrinsic curvature. Intrinsic curvature is the only one relevant to GTR and does not depend on spacetime being embedded in any higher-dimensional boondoggle. But if the question is merely that "what makes [a falling] body choose [a particular orbit]?", the answer to that is is its location and initial velocity.

Answer (score -1):

We cannot say that it bends in a particular direction because space-time in relativity is 4-dimensional. The space-time diagram which we see frequently is just a simple way of explaining it in two dimensions because 4-dimensional space is hard to visualize.

Comment: Could one say that the 'direction' is another axis 'g' perpendicular to x,y and z?

Comment: Well, I cannot say anything for sure as I am not an expert but as the 4th dimension is the time dimension, we can visualize a 3-dimensional space for every value of time.

Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=M9sbdrPVfOQ) video. It's not directly related to this question but might be helpful.